# hwnd is udefined c++ import of winuser.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```c++
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winuser.h>
#include <iostream>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

using namespace std;

typedef struct tagRECT
{
    LONG    left;
    LONG    top;
    LONG    right;
    LONG    bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT, NEAR *NPRECT, FAR *LPRECT;

int main()
{
    RECT newrect;
    AdjustWindowRect(&newrect, WS_BORDER, true);
    cout << "Hello, world, from Visual C++!" << endl;

}
```

This code cann't be compiled, it has more than 500 errors
The most occurring is **HWND is undefined**.
I am confused because winuser is standard header.
How to fix it please? Main goal is to program code that
will be giving me size of window of hwnd, this was
some first sample how to get near the goal with
AdjustWindowRect function.

Answer (score 5):

Never include `<winuser.h>` directly, include `<windows.h>` instead, perhaps with `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` defined first in order to cut down on what all is brought in by that header.

Comment: @Coolman please don't post screenshots without also posting the actual full error text. We can't see the complete error messages in your screenshot, but your errors are clearly related to Interlocked intrinsics. Add `#include <intrin.h>` and appropriate `#pragma intrinsic` statements to your code. See the [`_InterlockedDecrement`
 documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockeddecrement-intrinsic-functions?view=vs-2019) for a code example. See [Compiler intrinsics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/compiler-intrinsics?view=vs-2019) for more details.